# Making an array sql GROUP query play nicely with a php array (Simple)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am accessing a database with 500,000 rows, each of which has an entry for male (value 1), or female (value 2) in the column sex.

However, on trying to get it to display these numbers, I get the text: "*There were 373 males and females.*" Both numbers should be above 100,000.

What obvious syntax mistake am I missing?

```
$query = "SELECT sex, COUNT(*) FROM data GROUP BY sex"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$sexdb = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $totalmale = $sexdb["1"]; 
    $totalfemale = $sexdb["2"];

echo "<p>There were ".$totalmale." males and ".$totalfemale." females.</p>";
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn't split this into two small queries? Doesn't seen like this query makes sense at all. And the "Simple" in your title adds nothing to the question.

Comment: Sorry, not super familiar with the naming rules. I'm fairly sure it should easily be able to give me an array with the total number of males and that of females. Seems clunky to need two SQL queries for that?

Comment: Take a loot at Sarath' answer he uses two subqueries to get the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I changed to PDO, after the rightful abuse for mysql_* above.

My final code:

```
$sexquery = $connection->query("SELECT thesex, COUNT(*) AS sex FROM data GROUP BY thesex");
$sexdb = $sexquery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$results = array();          
foreach($sexdb as $row) {
   $results[$row['thesex']] = $row['sex'];
}

var_dump($results);
```

Which gives a nice clean array with the index being the row value, and the count as the corresponding value. This would scale nicely if there were more values.

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(4) "3668"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "1947"
}
```

My only question remaining is is there a way to make PDO play nicely and format the array neatly as a flat array without needing the loop in the middle...?

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
    $query = "SELECT (select count(sex) from data where sex=1) as maleCount, 
             (select count(sex) from data where sex=2) as femaleCount,
             COUNT(*) FROM data GROUP BY sex"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $sexdb = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $totalmale = $sexdb["maleCount"]; 
    $totalfemale = $sexdb["femaleCount"];

echo "<p>There were ".$totalmale." males and ".$totalfemale." females.</p>";
```

Comment: @bigonroad Remember to use `$sexdb["0"];` for male and `$sexdb["1"];` for female with this query.

Comment: You need to use `mysql_fetch_assoc` to be able to use `maleCount` as index.

Comment: Also it's advised to stop using `mysql_*` as it is deprecated. Try to start using `mysqli_*` or PDO

Comment: While the new queries do indeed show one way that this can be done they do not answer the original question correctly.
The problem with the OP is that he only fetches 1 row from his query results so will never get the second count contained in the second row. The fetching of results is a lesson that needs to be learnt. So we should be pointing this out.

Comment: Yeh that was my aim in terms of learning. Then its scalable more neatly when there are more than 2 values involved. What code should I use for storing to and returning from an array?

Comment: @DavidSoussan can you recommend what I should do then, for better scalability?